# Div Container min-height bug

Tags: css, html

Hi I got the following problem:
I use min-height:230px because the text within the div needs this height. But the Iphone needs another height so it should increase to like 320px.
My idea was to use height:auto so it automatically fits the height to the text but for some reason it doesn't work. 
The website is http://www.sterntaufe-deutschland.de/ please check the content below "Über Sterntaufe Deutschland" the 4 text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reset `min-height` by setting `height`. You should reset (or not specify at all) `min-height` itself.

By the way, consider using `display: inline-block` for each item so there would not be need to specify any height since they would align vertically automatically. For example:

```css
UL.services {font-size: 0; }

UL.services > LI {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul class="services">
    <li>
        <h3>30 Tage Rückgaberecht</h3>
        <p>Wir taufen nur gut sichtbare Sterne!</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3>Schneller Versand</h3>
        <p>Durch unsere langjährige Erfahrung.</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3>Das Sterntaufenregister</h3>
        <p>Wir sind Partner des Sterntaufenregisters.</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3>Wir sind für Sie da</h3>
        <p>Sollten Sie bei uns einen Stern kaufen.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To reset the min-height set it to zero (0) see also here: http://www.css4you.de/min-height.html
But to reset the height you should use 'auto' as default-value, see also here: http://www.css4you.de/height.html